# Orthonormal basis of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

I practice some exercises in linear algebra and suddendly I have to compute a orthonormal basis for the subspace $\mathbb{M}_{2,2}$ of the following matrices given below.
$$V_1=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix},\;\;\; V_2=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \;\;\;\text{ and }\;\;\; V_3=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Here is my approach. I want to compute $V_1'$, $V_2'$, $V_3'$ as I would do when using this method for vectors.
$$V_1=V_1'=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Second,
$$V_2'=V_2-\frac{\langle V_2,V_1' \rangle}{||V_1'||^2}V_1'=\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & 1\\ 
-1/2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Third is
$$V_3'=V_3-\frac{\langle V_3,V_1' \rangle}{||V_1'||^2}V_1'-\frac{\langle V_3,V_2' \rangle}{||V_2'||^2}V_2'=\begin{bmatrix}
-1/2 & 0\\ 
1/2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
I will now normalize them
$$\tilde{V_1}=\frac{V_1}{||V_1||}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix},\;\;\; \tilde{V_2}=\frac{V_2}{||V_2||}=\begin{bmatrix}
1/3 & 2/3\\ 
-1/3 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \;\;\; \text{ and }\;\;\; \tilde{V_3}=\frac{V_3}{||V_3||}=\begin{bmatrix}
-1/3 & 0\\ 
1/3 & 2/3
\end{bmatrix}$$
Therefore my orthonormal basis spanned by $V_1,V_2,V_3$ is $span\{\tilde{V_1},\tilde{V_2},\tilde{V_3}\}$.

I am not sure if my method are correct because I have never tried to use this method on matrices but just on vectors. Anyway if it's wrong, please correct me. Thanks

Comment: What inner product are you using for the matrices?

Comment: Your method is fine in that you've constructed an *orthogonal* set of vectors, but you haven't normalized them.  You need to compute, for instance, $\tilde{V}_1/\lVert\tilde{V}_1\rVert$.

Comment: @march thank you! For the inner product I have used $\langle A, B \rangle=Tr(A^tB)$. And further I've added the calculations of normalized matrices. If I compute the norm of the matrices I normalized then I get 1.

Comment: I think you're dividing by $\lVert \tilde{V}\rVert^2=\langle \tilde{V},\tilde{V}\rangle$, when you should be doing $\lVert \tilde{V}\rVert=\sqrt{\langle \tilde{V},\tilde{V}\rangle}$ in the normalization at the end.  Then I believe it is correct!

Comment: @march have a look. I've posted an answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

By using the suggestion in comment, I end with the following,
$$\tilde{V_1}=\frac{V_1'}{||V_1'||}=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & 0\\ 
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & 0
\end{bmatrix},\;\;\; \tilde{V_2}=\frac{V_2'}{||V_2'||}=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\sqrt{6}}{6} & \frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}\\ 
-\frac{\sqrt{6}}{6} & 0
\end{bmatrix} \;\;\; \text{ and }\;\;\; \tilde{V_3}=\frac{V_3'}{||V_3'||}=\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{\sqrt{6}}{6} & 0\\ 
\frac{\sqrt{6}}{6} & \frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}
\end{bmatrix}$$
however computing the norm of, let's say $\tilde{V_1}$ in Maple I get something that is not equal to 1. But when normalize things I should end with something that has a norm equal to 1??

Comment: This is not an answer. It's a comment to your own question.

Comment: Sorry my bad. But do you think my comment looks right?

Comment: For *every* norm, we *always* have $\left\|\frac v{\|v\|}\right\|=1$. So, you cannot be right.

Comment: Ahhh! I get it now! Thanks. I did a wrong computation and therefore did not get 1. Now I do actually get 1.